# Calculating the specific values of a column considering if they are within a group that is not under "group_by"

Tags: r

I am working with R and I have a data set that looks like this...

```
Condition  TargetWord             WordProduced        WPcondition    realValue                                                               1          Target1                  table                 A              .025
1          Target1                  word                  B              .009
1          Target1                  chair                 A              .005
1          Target1                  pole                  C              .015
1          Target1                  skate                 D              .023
1          Target2                  car                   B              .014
1          Target2                  house                 A              .018
1          Target2                  shoes                 A              .019
1          Target2                  girl                  A              .011
1          Target2                  life                  C              .020
2          Target3                  computer              D              .007
2          Target3                  ball                  B              .008
2          Target3                  court                 F              .009
2          Target3                  plane                 C              .035
2          Target3                  sky                   D              .008
2          Target4                  tree                  A              .051
2          Target4                  five                  C              .006
2          Target4                  help                  D              .003
2          Target4                  shave                 A              .006
2          Target4                  love                  B              .028
```

I need to calculate the average realValue of A's that are within WPcondition. So, I need an output like this.

```
Condition  TargetWord    MEANrealValue    
  1           Target1          .006
  1           Target2          .0096
  2           Target3          .0
  2           Target4          .0114
```

So, since the target1 have two A's within WPcondition we calculate their real value. This is, .025+.005 = .003/5 (total of targets) = .006

Since target 3 did not have an A within the WPcondition, we are not supossed to calculate the real value and just give to it a 0.

In other words, I need to group by TargetWord and calculate the real values of the A's, dividing the total by 5 which is the total amount of times that the target words repeat themself and if the target word did no produced an A, we just give them a 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of `WPcondition` and the sum of `realValue` of `WPcondition` A in separate dataframes and join them.

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "
Condition  TargetWord             WordProduced        WPcondition    realValue                                                               
1          Target1                  table                 A              .025
1          Target1                  word                  B              .009
1          Target1                  chair                 A              .005
1          Target1                  pole                  C              .015
1          Target1                  skate                 D              .023
1          Target2                  car                   B              .014
1          Target2                  house                 A              .018
1          Target2                  shoes                 A              .019
1          Target2                  girl                  A              .011
1          Target2                  life                  C              .020
2          Target3                  computer              D              .007
2          Target3                  ball                  B              .008
2          Target3                  court                 F              .009
2          Target3                  plane                 C              .035
2          Target3                  sky                   D              .008
2          Target4                  tree                  A              .051
2          Target4                  five                  C              .006
2          Target4                  help                  D              .003
2          Target4                  shave                 A              .006
2          Target4                  love                  B              .028",
header = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
total <- dat %>% 
  group_by(TargetWord) %>% 
  summarise(total_WP = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
    
dat1 <- dat %>% 
  filter(WPcondition == "A") %>% 
  group_by(TargetWord) %>% 
  summarise(realValue = sum(realValue)) %>% 
  right_join(total, by = "TargetWord") %>% 
  mutate(realValue = replace_na(realValue, 0),
         MEANrealValue = realValue/total_WP)

dat1

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   TargetWord realValue total_WP MEANrealValue
#   <chr>          <dbl>    <int>         <dbl>
# 1 Target1        0.03         5        0.006 
# 2 Target2        0.048        5        0.0096
# 3 Target4        0.057        5        0.0114
# 4 Target3        0            5        0
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you need only real means for As. So, firstly, I filtered the data to have only As in it, then I grouped TargetWord and summarised. If my solution is not something that you really wanted, give me the sign :)

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  filter(WPcondition == "A") %>%
  group_by(TargetWord) %>%
  summarise(MEANrealValue = mean(realValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I have used dplyr to reach the result you have asked for. I have named the dataframe as 'Data'. First I grouped by Target Word and WPcondition to the calculate the Sum realValue when WPcondition = A using an ifelse statement. Then I used ungroup to then be able to use group_by with only TargetWord in order to divde the SUMrealValue by the number of rows (n) in each TargetWord group to reach MEANrealValue.

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(TargetWord, WPcondition) %>% 
  mutate(SUMrealvalue=ifelse(WPcondition == 'A', sum(realValue), 0))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  group_by(TargetWord)%>%
  mutate(MEANrealValue = SUMrealvalue / n())%>%
  arrange(TargetWord, desc(MEANrealValue))%>%
  select(Condition, TargetWord, MEANrealValue)%>%
  distinct(TargetWord, .keep_all=T)
```